# DropDown Menu from Panel on Mouse Hover

Tags: panel

[image: Screenshot]I was wondering if there is any way to make the Global Menu   (File, Edit.......Messages etc)   Drop Down Automatically when I Hover my Mouse Pointer above it instead of Clicking them???  Im using Ubuntu 11.10 Unity Desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) and create a script to put at "Startup Applications" like this:

```
  
#!/bin/bash
#
# version 0.06 by desgua 
#
# To click at global menu
#
############################################################
h=
d=

function hittop {

eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)

if [ "$Y" -lt "24" ] ; then
h=1
d=0
fi
}

while :
do

if [ "$h" = "1" ] ; then 
xdotool click 1
sleep .1
h=0
fi

eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
if [ "$Y" -gt "24" ] ; then
d=1
fi

if [ "$d" = "1" ] ; then
hittop
fi

########################
# Uncomment the following line if your cpu gets hot...
# sleep .2 
######################## 
done

exit 0
```

---

**Step by step instructions:**

1) Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gedit ~/.click.global.menu` then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> - this will open a blank file.

2) Paste the previous script at the blank file and save.

3) Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gnome-terminal` - this will open a terminal.

4) At terminal paste `chmod +x ~/.click.global.menu`

5) Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and paste `gnome-session-properties` - this will open the Startup Applications.

6) At Startup Applications hit "Add".

7) At dialog paste `Global Menu` at "Name:" and `~/.click.global.menu` at "Command:" as showed in this picture:

[image]

8) Install [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool) (just click at the link and hit "Install")

9) Logout and Log back in.

10) Have fun ;-)

**Automated way**

1) Just open a terminal and paste this:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool && cd ~/ && wget -c http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/click.global.menu && chmod +x ~/click.global.menu && ~/click.global.menu
```

Comment: isnt there a way to manually start it up instead of automatic?

Comment: step 1 isnt opening anything, it just shows a file, that too is not clickable

Comment: Do you know how to open a terminal? (Applications > Accessories > Terminal) You can substitute `Press Alt + F2` for `Open a terminal`. And yes you can start it manually by opening a terminal and pasting `~/.click.global.menu`.

Comment: I did everything as you have said.... then.... nothing happens...

Comment: Can you open a terminal and paste `sudo apt-get install xdotool && cd ~/ && wget -c http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/click.global.menu && chmod +x ~/click.global.menu && ~/click.global.menu` then tell what happens?

Comment: i get something called find client some random numbers and "unary operator expected all in an infinite loop"

Comment: Seems like that it is working. Then, when you get your mouse up to the menu, is there an automatic click?

Comment: Can you paste this on a terminal and post me the screenshot: `xdotool mousemove 100 15 && gnome-screenshot` ?

Comment: ive posted a screenshot

Comment: It looks fine. Can you paste this on a terminal and see if it works? `h= ; d= ; while : ; do function hittop { eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell) ; if [ "$Y" -lt "24" ] ; then h=1 ; d=0 ; fi ; } ; if [ $h = 1 ] ; then xdotool mousemove 100 15 click 1 ; sleep .1 ; xdotool mousemove $X $Y ; h=0 ; fi ; eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell) ; if [ "$Y" -gt "24" ] ; then d=1 ; fi ; if [ $d = 1 ] ; then hittop ; fi ; done`

Comment: nothin happened:(:(:(:(:

Comment: If you paste `xdotool mousemove 100 15 click 1` the menu DropDown?

Comment: no... the menu dodn dropdwn

Comment: what does it mean by UNARY OPERATOR EXPECTED?

Comment: This indicates a little mistake in my script that I've already correct, thank you for pointing this. See more here: http://linuxcommand.org/wss0100.php

Comment: it worked, i removed everything and did everything from starting, SHAANDAAR

Comment: That is great! :-)

Answer (score -1):

This is a small answer but it could solve that lazy issue of yours :P Go to `System>Preferences>Mouse` -- now go to the accessibility tab and check the box "initiate click when stopping pointer movement". This will enable click when not moving your mouse.

Comment: In 11.10 this can be accomplished with System Settings -- Universal Access -- Pointing & Clicking tab -- Hover Click ON. You'll be able to select right, left double or drag. However, the result of the click will depend on where the cursor is positioned and unfortunately you get that click weather you wanted it or not.